# modify the group match output of a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to modify the group match output of a javascript regex

psudo code:

```
var from_another_script=/file:(\w+)/;
var inp = 'file:name';
var matches = inp.match(from_another_script);
```

normally output would be “name”

I would like to modify the regex to get output as “name_file”

I have seen some regex references (not js and not match) as 
/file:(\w+)/$1_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `match`, but you can do this:

```
var inp = 'file:name';
var output = inp.replace(/file:(\w+)/, '$1_file');
```

What you had in another language wasn't just a regex : it was a regex AND a replacement pattern. You can't add `_file` with just a regex. If you can change the calling code, here's a solution:

```
var from_another_script={
   regex: /file:(\w+)/,
   replacementPattern: '$1_file'
}
var inp = 'file:name';
var output = inp.replace(from_another_script.regex, from_another_script.replacementPattern);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "from_another_scrip"t regex is must contain the modifier as it comes from another script.

Comment: You mean you want to keep the other lines unchanged ? You can't : match can't add anything.

Comment: Yea I was afraid that was the case, I could not find anything in the docs about it, so I will have to do some serious rework in the other script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
inp.replace(/file:(\w+)/, '$1_file');
```